# Unable to Fill multidimensional arrays with sql rows

Tags: php, sql, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm currently having trouble saving individual rows into a multi-dimensional arrays. The current code below (php) does not create a multi-dimensional array even though $Prow should be an array itself. The echo at the end of the code returns no values, any help? 
EDIT: ps, the query works perfectly.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Products WHERE Tags LIKE '%atmega%'"; 
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$xx = 0;

while($Prow = $result->fetch_assoc()){ 
 $PArray[$xx] = $Prow;
 $xx += 1;
}
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('".$PArray[0][0]."');</script>";
```

Comment: See Ray answer for main problem. Side note: you don't need to increment array index with `$xx`: you can simply use: `$PArray = array();   while(...)  $PArray[] = $PRow;`

Comment: Why do you think it's not a multidimensional array? It is, but the indexes of the second dimension are column names, not numbers.

Comment: Try `$PArray[0]['id']`, for instance.

Comment: Barmar thank you! i wish i could accept your comment as my answer but unfortunately i cant. It works perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to know what your array looks like then do a `print_r()` on it.

Oh and you should be checking for errors after a call to `->query()`

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Products WHERE Tags LIKE '%atmega%'"; 
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ( $result === FALSE ) {
    echo $conn->error;
    exit;
}
$xx = 0;

while($Prow = $result->fetch_assoc()){ 
   $PArray[$xx] = $Prow;
   $xx += 1;
}
print_r($PArray);
```

To simplify your code you could do

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Products WHERE Tags LIKE '%atmega%'"; 
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ( $result === FALSE ) {
    echo $conn->error;
    exit;
}

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){ 
   $PArray[] = $row;
}
print_r($PArray);
```

But to get a numeric index on the returned array rather than an associative array use `->fetch_row()`

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Products WHERE Tags LIKE '%atmega%'"; 
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ( $result === FALSE ) {
    echo $conn->error;
    exit;
}

while($row = $result->fetch_row()){ 
   $PArray[] = $row;
}
print_r($PArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `mysqli`, `$result->fetch_assoc()` returns an associative array, not a zero indexed array. The indexes are your column headers.   Try just  `$result->fetch_row()` if you want an enumerated array.